# how to separate lists into different divs dynamically

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-blade

Good day,

I have a list of categories in my page, but anytime it could be added or removed. Can you please help me formulate a loop to divide my lists into a maximum of 5 list per div.

ex.

```
foreach($categories as $cat)
  <label><input type ="checkbox"><?php echo $cat->name ?></label></br>
endforeach
```

the above code will generate a list of checkboxes in 1 column

[image]

so I tried this loop

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
    @foreach($categories as $cat)
    @if($count == 0)
    <div class="col-md-4">
    @elseif($count == 5)
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    </div>
    @endif
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$cat->xid}}">{{$cat->category}}</label><br>
    <?php $count++; ?>
    @endforeach
```

and it generates like this

[image]

but it only wraps the first 5 elements on the list and the next 5 is not working. Can you help me please :) suggestions are really appreciated

Comment: in this case, we need some data to work with because you said it worked with some and not the others.

Comment: i don't think it is vanilla php, is it blade?

Comment: hello @DanielCheung yeah its Blade. :)

Comment: i suggest you add that as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is your code to which I modified would generate the required layout. you will need to apply CSS to the class="col-md-4" to seperate each block as per your requirement.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
 @foreach($categories as $cat)
 @if($count == 0)
   <div class="col-md-4">
 @endif

 @if($count> 0 && $count%5 == 0)
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
 @endif

 <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$cat->xid}}">{{$cat->category}}     
 </label><br>
 <?php $count++; ?>
@endforeach

@if($count <= 5)
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in vanilla PHP, but you can easily use the logic in your blade template. I tested it, works perfectly fine.

```
<?php
   $categories = ['test','test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7',
'test','test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7','test','test1',
'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7','test','test1', 'test2', 'test3',
'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7'];
$end = end($categories);

$count = 1;
foreach($categories as $cat){ 
   if($count == 1 || $count % 5 == 1){
      echo '<div class="col-md-5">';
   }
?>

<label><input type ="checkbox"><?php echo $cat ?></label></br>

<?php
   if(($count % 5 == 0) && $count != 0 || ($cat == $end)){
     echo '</div>';
   }
   $count++;
} 
?>
```